# xamarin iOS c# SearchBar stuck and work hyper slowly when Search in ListView items

Tags: c#, ios, mysql, xamarin, searchbar

Use: Xamarin on Visual Studio for Mac

I have a sample SearchBar with filled ListView from database with places.
When I start the app I see the places in the ListView, but when I click on the SearchBar and want to search some item from database the SearchBar is stuck..
Example: I try to enter "Plovdiv".. but I can't ... just Enter P... after 25 second the search enter "l"... after 40 second i see the other "o".. and SearchBar work super slowly for hint...

My code from MainPage.cs:

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public string GlobalLat;
    public string GlobalLong;

    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;



    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listView.ItemsSource = GetContacts();
        this.BindingContext = this;

        Task task = GetUserLocationAsync();
    }

    public class Contacts
    {
        public string Place { get; set; }
    }

    IEnumerable<Contacts> GetContacts(string searchText = null)
    {
        server = "192.168.0.1,3306";
        database = "dbName";
        uid = "username";
        password = "";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        var contacts = new List<Contacts>();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT place FROM places ORDER BY place", connection);

        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var place = new Contacts
                {
                    Place = reader[0].ToString()
                };

                contacts.Add(place);

            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
            return contacts;
        return contacts.Where(p => p.Place.StartsWith(searchText));
    }

    private void ListView_Refreshing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView.ItemsSource = GetContacts();
        listView.EndRefresh();
    }
}
void SearchBar_TextChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listView.ItemsSource = GetContacts(e.NewTextValue);
    }

    void Btn_Search(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

This is the code from MainPage.xaml file:

```
<StackLayout>  
            <SearchBar
               Placeholder="Enter city"
               TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged"
               SearchButtonPressed="Btn_Search"></SearchBar>  
            <ListView
                HeightRequest="250"
                x:Name="listView" >  
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                    <DataTemplate>  
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Place}">  
                    </TextCell>  
                    </DataTemplate>  
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
            </ListView>  
        </StackLayout>
```

So the Search work hyper slowly and He stuck every time when I hit on the her and want to search..

[image: SearchBar Stuck When Click on it]

Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: are you still loading 1000s of rows from your DB into the UI?  And why have you not posted any of your search button event handlers?

Comment: Can you show me how ?

Comment: every time you type a SINGLE CHARACTER you are opening an SQL connection and querying the entire DB and then filtering the results.  So if they type 4 characters is does that FOUR times.  That is extremely expensive.  It would be much more efficient to just filter the dataset that you already have in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, keep a local list of Contacts, you do not need to refresh from the remote DB every time

```
List<Contact> data;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    listView.ItemsSource = data = GetContacts();
    this.BindingContext = this;

    Task task = GetUserLocationAsync();
}
```

then, when you search, use the data you already have loaded, do NOT continually query the remote database

```
void SearchBar_TextChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listView.ItemsSource = data.Where(p => p.Place.StartsWith(e.NewTextValue));
}
```